# How to pass value from one method to another?

Tags: c#

I am working on a employee paycheck calculator using several private methods. The methods will determine overtime hours and regular hours. I also must create methods for regular pay and overtime pay. My question is can I feed the results from the hours methods into the methods that will determine pay? If that is possible, how would it work? The method in question is CalculateBasePayAmount--can I pass a result from another method into here?

Here is a look at what I've got so far. Thanks for any help anyone could provide!

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Determine Hours Method
    private decimal DetermineBasePayHours(decimal parhoursWorked)
    {
        decimal baseHours = 0; 
        decimal overtimeHours = 0;

        if (parhoursWorked <= 40)
        {
            baseHours = parhoursWorked;
        }
        else if (parhoursWorked > 40)
        {
           overtimeHours = parhoursWorked - 40;
           baseHours = parhoursWorked - overtimeHours ;

        }
        return baseHours;

    }

    private decimal DetermineOverTimeHours(decimal parHoursWorked, string parCategory)
    {
        decimal overtimeHours = 0;



        if (parHoursWorked > 40 && parCategory!="MGR")
        {
            overtimeHours = parHoursWorked - 40;
        }
        return overtimeHours;
    }

    private decimal CalculateBasePayAmount(decimal basePayHours, string parCategory)
    {

        decimal basePay = 0;
        decimal mgrWage = 20;
        decimal salesWage = 15;
        decimal staffWage = 10;


        basePayHours= DetermineBasePayHours(basePayHours);

        if(parCategory == "MGR" && basePayHours > 40)
        {
            basePay = 40 * mgrWage;
        }
        else
        {
            basePay = basePayHours * mgrWage;
        }

        if (parCategory =="SR")
        {
            basePay = basePayHours * salesWage;
        }

        else if (parCategory == "STF")
        {
            basePay = basePayHours * staffWage;
        }
        return basePay;
    }





    protected void butCalcPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////1. Declare Variables
        //decimal mgrWage = 20;
        //decimal salesWage = 15;
        //decimal staffWage = 10;
        //decimal basePay = 0M;

        //decimal salesOvertime = 22.50M;
        //decimal staffOvertime = 15;
        //decimal overtimeHours = 0;
        //decimal overtimePay = 0;
        //decimal totalPay = 0;

        decimal totalHours = 0;
        decimal bpHours;
        decimal otHours;
        string empCat;
        decimal basePay;

        //2. Get Values for Variables
        totalHours = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNumberHours.Text);
        empCat = Convert.ToString(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);



        // 3. Methods Called
        bpHours = DetermineBasePayHours(totalHours);
        otHours = DetermineOverTimeHours(totalHours, empCat);
        basePay = CalculateBasePayAmount(totalHours, empCat);




       // 4. Display Results

        lblbasePay.Text = "Base Pay " + basePay.ToString("C");e here
```

Comment: @Steve: come on, you were a beginner too at some point; help the guy out!

Comment: @frenchie well...all the information he needs are in the second chapter of an introduction book. If he got stuck on trying to understand something then sure we are here to help. But this is just too basic.

Answer (score 1):

> can I feed the results from the hours methods into the methods that will determine pay?

In a manner of speaking, yes.  Though I think the confusion is coming from the way you describe it and the terminology you use.

It's not entirely clear to me what specific values you're looking for in this case, but it looks like your methods essentially just accept some values, run some calculations, and return some values.  Any code which call those functions will then get those returned values and can use them to call other functions.  As a contrived example:

```
private int Method1(int someValue)
{
    // perform some calculation, then...
    return anotherValue;
}

private int Method2(int someValue)
{
    // perform some calculation, then...
    return anotherValue;
}
```

Then consuming code would be able to use those functions to perform larger calculations:

```
var calculatedValue = Method1(5);
var furtherCalculatedValue = Method2(calculatedValue);
```

This essentially "feeds the results" of the first function into the second function, in the sense that the result of the first function is then used as an input for the second function.  The functions don't have any knowledge of each other, they don't "feed data to each other", in this case they simply return values based on calculations.  Consuming code can choose to use the result of one function as a parameter to another function.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was meaning, how can output from one method be used as input to another method. I believe this has got me headed in the right direction. Appreciate it.

Comment: I edited the original code to reflect what I did by using your suggestions. It works, but it just seems like there could be a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @gilesitis: The overall code can probably be improved a decent amount through some refactoring.  There are industry patterns for just that: http://refactoring.com/catalog/  There's nothing inherently wrong with separating out different calculations into different methods and being very explicit about what each value means.  Keep in mind that *shorter* code isn't always *better* code :)

Comment: Thanks @David, that Web site looks like it could be very helpful. I was just wondering about trimming down my code some because I'm beginning to get lost among the variables and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to read more on programming and how/why we have methods that return values that the ones you mentioned above. Using your code above you'll want to use their values like this:

```
// basePayHours is the decimal amount returned by DetermineBasePayHours.
var basePayHours = DetermineBasePayHours(parhoursWorked);
// overTimeHours is the decimal amount returned by DetermineOverTimeHours.
var overTimeHours = DetermineOverTimeHours(parHoursWorked, parCategory);
// basePayAmount is the decimal amount returned by CalculateBasePayAmount.
var basePayAmount = CalculateBasePayAmount(basePayHours, parCategory);
```

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to understand methods, but it's been a little tough to grasp. If you guys know of any good online resources please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If C# is what you want to learn, you could start here: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ or for any other language/framework: http://www.codecademy.com/learn

Answer (score -2):

delegate can also be used when a method is needed from another one .

Think of YourMethod return 0. Would you want to make MyMethod result 0 this is possible by using the MyMethod delegate parameter because you could allow MyMethod make its result the same as YourMethod return.
Isn't that exactly like you'd make YourMethod the calculation that you'd decide MyMethod should take into account?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean with code?

Comment: There are plenty of code examples. The main thing is whether delegate can help the post author or not. I think so.