# Extracting value of for-loop count at runtime c#

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Here is my dilemma:

```
public void checkCountProgress(int countProgress, int totalDataSize){ //work done here}

public void func1(int passVar)
{
  for(int = 0; i<= 2000; i+=64){
     //do work
      checkCountProgress(i, 2000);
  }      
}
```

Everytime when I iterate through the for-loop, i obviously changes by     increments of 64. The checkCountProgressFunction gives me the value of i at whichever point my client connection to the remote host gets disconnected. So I want to continue writing and sending data to the network from where I left off. I would manually stop my server, change the value of i in the parameter of the calling function, run, update service reference from client side and continue but now I need to automate that because I now have to include multiple connections to the host. When I look at some examples, it usually refers to passing a parameter from one function, getting its value and using it in another method ([How to pass value from one method to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207430/how-to-pass-value-from-one-method-to-another) ) which is entirely different to what I want to do. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean using settings to store the value at which the loop was stopped?
If so, here's an example of how to use them

In your project's **Properties**, in the **Settings** tab add a new setting of you desired value type and set the scope to **User**. For my example I created one named **ValueToResume** of type **Int** and initial value of 0.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int initialLoopValue = Properties.Settings.Default.ValueToResume;
        for (int i = initialLoopValue; i <= 2000; i += 64)
        {
            //do work
            checkCountProgress(i, 2000);
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reset(); //Loop was completed, we can reset the setting to 0
    }

    public static void checkCountProgress(int countProgress, int totalDataSize)
    {
        if (countProgress > 600)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.ValueToResume = countProgress;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Environment.Exit(0); //force application exit
        }
    }
}
```

On the second run, the loop will be initialized at value 640

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in depth answer. I will definitely try it out.

Comment: The only issue I have is that you are explicitly setting a value for countProgress in your if statement. The connection can be lost at any stage, not specifically 600. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @LindaMotaung so just remove the if condition so that the setting value is updated and saved every time checkCountProgress() is fired

Comment: Thank you. I used that approach. Apparently I can't use property variables and I would have to do this programmatically in code :-(